# Lazy loading feature module not working

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular4-router

I have a app.routing.ts file as below

```
    import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { SalesComponent } from './advisory/sales.component';

    const appRoutes: Routes = [
        {
            path:'admin',loadChildren:'app/auth/admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
        },
        {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: '/main',
            pathMatch: 'full'
        },
        {
            path: 'main', component: SalesComponent,
            data: { apptitle: 'main', subtitle: 'main' }
        },

    ];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, 
        { useHash: true },
        )],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And a feature module admin.module.ts file as below

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { AdminComponent } from './admin.component';
    import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{
    path: '',
    component: AdminComponent,
    }
    ]),

    declarations: [AdminComponent]
    })

    export class AdminModule { }
```

If I hit localhost:4200/#/main in the browser, it is working but if I enter localhost:4200/#/admin or localhost:4200/admin- it refreshes and loads the same main page. Any idea why this may be happening and any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a StackBlitz where it works https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f568ym?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

You should use a relative path.

`path:'admin',loadChildren:'./auth/admin/admin.module#AdminModule'`

Also you may have an issue with the routes defined within the `AdminModule`

I would change the syntax in the AdminModule to this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const adminRoutes: Routes = [
  {
      path:'',
      component:AdminComponent,
      pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(adminRoutes)
  ],
  declarations: [AdminComponent]
})

export class AdminModule { }
```

Comment: its the same answer i posted below

Comment: You didn't change the path defined within the child module, so when the browser adds `/` it will cause a redirect

Comment: @AnthonyDiTomasso I tried adding both your suggestion. It stills loads the same main page what ever I try on the browser.

Comment: @user3447602 I added a stackblitz where it is working, check it out. I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I guess the path is wrong, you should use relative path instead,

```
 path:'admin',loadChildren:'./auth/admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
```